# How could I print to STDERR with Term::Screen?

Tags: perl, printing, terminal, screen, stderr

I'd like here to print the bold `hi!` to `STDERR`. Is that possible with [Term::Screen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aScreen)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';
use Term::Screen;

my $scr = new Term::Screen;
unless ( $scr ) { die " Something's wrong \n"; }
$scr->clrscr();
$scr->at(5,10)->bold()->puts("hi!")->normal();
$scr->at(11,0);
```

Comment: Could you explain what that would be useful for? I'm having a hard time seeing what you'd want to do with that.

Comment: I'd like to do this (from the `IO::Interactive` Documentation):  "You can also pass interactive a writable filehandle, in which case it writes to that filehandle if it is connected to a terminal (instead of writinbg to *STDOUT). Once again, the usual suspect is *STDERR:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Term::Screen, looking at its source, is hard-coded to write to `*STDOUT`

E.g. `sub at{}` that you are calling, in the source, has this:

`$this->term()->Tgoto( 'cm', $c, $r, *STDOUT );`

Therefore, you need to explicitly redirect all of STDOUT to STDERR:

```
open(my $backup_stdout, ">&STDOUT");
close(STDOUT);
open(STDOUT, ">&STDERR"); # This affects ALL of spawned child processes!
# *STDOUT = *STDERR; # This does the same but ONLY affects your process
```